# need understanding of while loop condition (see comment)

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
while (x >= 1000)
{
    cout << "M";
    x -= 1000;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how this while loop works? I understand the condition is for x is greater or equal to 1000, it will print out 'M'.

The part after that is what I actually don't understand, is it saying that it will keep subtracting a thousand from X and keep printing until the condition is false?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please keep in mind that appreciation is shown by upvotes and accepted answers (checkmarks). If you have any questions, the [FAQ] is a great resource especially the section on how to ask questions [FAQ#HowToAsk]

Comment: When you get answers, Upvote the good ones and accept the best!! Welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what it will do.

This translates roughly into:

While x is greater than or equal to 1000, do what is in the code block (over and over until the condition fails)

The code block then prints M and sets x equal to itself minus 1000. (`x -= 1000` is the same as `x = x - 1000`

Hypothetical:

```
x = 3000
x is greater than 1000
print M
x is set to 2000
loop resets and checks x...passes test
print M
x is set to 1000
loop resets and checks x...passes test because of = portion
print M
x is set to 0
loop resets and checks x...fails
moves to the code after the while code block
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (x >= 1000)   //x is greater than or equal to 1000
{                   //executes loop if condition true, else the statement after the loop block
    cout << "M";  // print M
    x -= 1000;    // x = x-1000
}                  //goes back to condition checking
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right!

```
x-=1000;
```

is actually

```
x=x-1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> it saying that it will keep subtracting a thousand from X and keep printing until the condition is false

Answer (score 0):

The program appears to be an inefficient way of writing

```
x %= 1000;
```

which is `x = x%1000`, where `%` is the modulus operator.

Your code reaches the same result by subsequent substraction, and stops when `x<1000`.